# Is there a simplier way to un-nest an array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

All,

How would you "un-nest" an array to make it easier to loop through?

How would you convert the array below...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key1] => data1
                    [key2] => data2
                    [key3] => data3
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key1] => data4
                    [key2] => data5
                    [key3] => data6
                )

        )
)
```

To something manageable like this.... ?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array {
        [key1] => data1
        [key2] => data2
        [key3] => data3
        }
    [1] => Array (
        [key1] => data4
        [key2] => data5
        [key3] => data6
        )
)
```

Comment: How did you create the array in the first place? That might be easier than restructuring it subsequently

Comment: you need a plain loop. what's the problem? where's your code?

Comment: In order to un-nest that array you are going to have to process it so where is the benefit?

Comment: @RiggsFolly: preprocessing have great benefits, if a lot of code touches the data structure afterwards.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Then I will point you to the first comment in the list

Comment: @RiggsFolly: yes, that comment made sense.

Comment: I have a database class that returns that the array like that. I think I'm looking for an "array flatten" function.

Comment: Then I would fix the database class

Comment: Nah, just get rid of it and use a proper one...

Comment: I'm using this: https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is!

```
 $newArray = array_map('end', $oldArray);
```

This code simply applies [`end`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) to each element of the source array and collects the results into a new array. For example, if such an element is

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [key1] => data1
                [key2] => data2
                [key3] => data3
            )
    )
```

the result of `end` will be

```
        Array
            (
                [key1] => data1
                [key2] => data2
                [key3] => data3
            )
```

Essentially `end` "unwraps" the inner arrays, thus getting rid of one nesting level. Since there's always only one subarray, you can also use `current` or `reset` with the same effect.

Comment: nice! functional programming ftw.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand why he's using 'end' as callback, or why this works.

Comment: Astounding. Thank you.

Comment: `array_map` is the classic functional mapping ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28higher-order_function%29 ), and for each element, `end` will return the last element in the array - just what you need (because there's only one element).

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks to you both!

Comment: Oh I was still in the flatten mindset, makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works for the test case, but the following will work for almost(?) any array:

```
$newArray = array_reduce($oldArray, 'array_merge', []));
```

This runs [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) starting with the first value and `[]`, then the second value and the result of the first `array_merge`, and so on until it returns the result of merging the carried value and the final value. This has the effect of unwrapping 1 layer.

Example:

```
$a = [ [ [ 'key1' => 'data1' ], [ 'key1' => 'data2' ] ], [ [ 'key1' => 'data3' ] ] ];
$a = array_reduce($a, 'array_merge', []);
print_r($a);

// output:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key1] => data1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key1] => data2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [key1] => data3
        )

)
```